# Latency from sequential yield calls in python

Tags: python, dataframe, pytorch, yield

I'm writing a code to read a set of `pandas.DataFrames` stored in h5 files and iterate over their rows. The aim of my code is to handle the dataset using a `pytorch` `IterableDataset`, but I belive my question below is not exclusive to `pytorch`.

Since reading each h5 from disk takes a a while, I have implemented the following logic

1. the code reads the first file from disk, and pre-fetches the second file asynchronously
2. once the first `DataFrame` is read out from disk, the code starts iterating over its rows (using `yield from)
3. once that iteration is done, the code reads the following file asynchronously and starts yielding from the one it prefetched before.

The code can be found here

```
def _load_next( file_list, index, device, labels, variables):
    if index >= len(file_list):
        return None
        
     thedata=pd.read_hdf(file_list[index], 'df')
     labels=torch.Tensor( thedata[labels].values).to(device)
     variables=torch.Tensor( thedata[variables].values).to(device)     

     return index, (labels,variables)   

class datasets( IterableDataset ):
    def __init__( self, path, device, variables, labels):
        self.files=glob.glob(path)
    self.device=device
        self.variables=variables
        self.labels=labels
        self.restart()
        
    def restart(self):
        print("Re-starting iterator")
        # read first file and submit prefetching of the following
        self.file_index, self.current_data=_load_next(self.files,0, self.device)
        self.prefetch=self.executor.submit(_load_next, self.files, self.file_index+1, self.device)   
        
    def __iter__(self):
       while True:
            yield from zip(self.current_data[0], self.current_data[1])
            result=self.prefetch.result()
            if result is None: 
                self.executor.shutdown(wait=False)
                raise StopIteration
            else:
                self.file_index, self.current_data = result
                self.prefetch=self.executor.submit(_load_next, self.files, self.file_index+1, self.device)
```

The logic works well, however each `yield from` call takes a few seconds, which introduces a (perhaps) unnecessary latency (the latency is actually longer than the time it takes to prefetch the following file).
**Is there a way to remove this latency, perhaps running `yield from` asynchronously? Other ideas are of course welcome! Thanks in advance!**

Comment: How does this work?  Nothing in your loop depends on `f`.  It looks like you're doing EVERY file in EVERY iteration.

Comment: @TimRoberts It's spaghetti code. The calls to `restart` and to `_load_next` have side effects of moving to the next file. The main loop could easily be `for _ in range(len(self.files)):` But, none of that addresses any latency in the `yield from`

Comment: apologies, there was a small copy&paste mistake, it should not be a `for` loop but a `while True`. And then  `_load_next` is called to force the update to the next file

Comment: Sounds like something is being lazily loaded / lazily evaluated. I'd step through the code (you do have a debugger in your environment, right?) and see what is taking the time. I'd lay my hat on something inside pytorch.

Comment: Remember that pytorch delays stuff as long as it can.  The actions in `_load_next` might not be done until the data is needed in the `yield`.

Comment: @MatBailie you were sort of right. The call to `yield` translates into three calls to `pytorch.Tensor.__iter__`  that take time but can be done asynchronously (which was my  question but I had mistakenly attributed the overhead to the `yield` call itself). Let me post the full code as possible answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the feedback received in the discussion, I managed to optimize the code even further - the problem was not in the `yield` call but on the fact that the `torch.Tensor` iterator that is ~slow but can be constructed asynchronously. The code reads like that below.

This is quite faster than the previous version, but I'm not fully satisfied: the neural network training and the prefetching seem to be competing for the same resources (the training slows down until the prefetching is done)

```
def _load_next( file_list, index, device, labels, variables):
    if index >= len(file_list):
        return None
        
     thedata=pd.read_hdf(file_list[index], 'df')
     labels=torch.Tensor( thedata[labels].values).to(device).__iter__()
     variables=torch.Tensor( thedata[variables].values).to(device).__iter__()    

     return index, (labels,variables)   

class datasets( IterableDataset ):
    def __init__( self, path, device, variables, labels):
        self.files=glob.glob(path)
        self.device=device
        self.variables=variables
        self.labels=labels
        self.restart()
        
    def restart(self):
        print("Re-starting iterator")
        # read first file and submit prefetching of the following
        self.file_index, self.current_data=_load_next(self.files,0, self.device)
        self.prefetch=self.executor.submit(_load_next, self.files, self.file_index+1, self.device)   
        
    def __iter__(self):
       while True:
            yield from zip(self.current_data[0], self.current_data[1])
            result=self.prefetch.result()
            if result is None: 
                self.executor.shutdown(wait=False)
                self.restart()
                break
            else:
                self.file_index, self.current_data = result
                self.prefetch=self.executor.submit(_load_next, self.files, self.file_index+1, self.device)
```